# How to do type checking in Golang fast?

Tags: go

I'm parsing a Go application using the following piece of code. Basically, I recursively visit all packages from a top-level directory and parse each package using `parser.ParseDir()` function.

`readPackages` is a helper function that walks all package directories starting from `path` and for each directory, it calls the given function with given base `path` and the relative directory.

```golang
import (
  "go/ast"
  "go/importer"
  "go/parser"
  "go/token"
  "go/types"
  "path/filepath"
  "strings"
)

func Parse(path string) error {
  fset := token.NewFileSet()

  moduleName := getModuleName()

  return readPackages(path, func(baseDir, relDir string) error {
    pkgDir := filepath.Join(baseDir, relDir)
    importPath := filepath.Join(moduleName, relDir)

    pkgs, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, pkgDir, nil, parser.AllErrors)
    if err != nil {
      return err
    }

    for pkgName, pkg := range pkgs {
      checker := &types.Config{
        IgnoreFuncBodies: true,
        FakeImportC:      true,
        Error:            nil,
        Importer:         importer.ForCompiler(fset, "source", nil),
      }

      files := make([]*goast.File, 0)
      for fileName, file := range pkg.Files {
        if strings.HasSuffix(fileName, "_test.go") {
          continue
        }
        files = append(files, file)
      }

      info := &gotypes.Info{
        Defs:  map[*goast.Ident]gotypes.Object{},
        Uses:  map[*goast.Ident]gotypes.Object{},
        Types: map[goast.Expr]gotypes.TypeAndValue{},
      }

      _, err = checker.Check(importPath, fset, files, info)
      if err != nil {
        return err
      }

      for fileName, file := range pkg.Files {
        if strings.HasSuffix(fileName, "_test.go") {
          continue
        }
        // Process file AST ...
      }
    }

    return nil
  })
}
```

When running this `Parse` function on a real application (a service that imports http, gRPC, etc.), it takes a very very long time for type checking to complete. I tried using the `importer.Default()` which does not resolve none built-in packages.

My question is what's the correct or an efficient way of type checking `ast.File`s in Go? How does the Go compiler itself do this so fast? Why is it taking so long using `importer.ForCompiler`?